# How to manage/package dependencies in a reusable react library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am creating my first `reactjs` library that uses [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) and [react-google-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts) as well as a number of other 3rd party libraries. I'm using webpack (version 3.5.6) as my bundler and so far I have the following `webpack.config.js` file...

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib')
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')

const WebpackConfig = {

    entry: {
        app: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: 'TestComponent'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                options: {
                    presets: [ 'react', 'es2015', 'stage-2' ]
                }
            }
        ],
    },
}

// webpack production config.
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ) {

    WebpackConfig.externals = {
        'react': 'react',
        'react-dom': 'react-dom'
    }

    WebpackConfig.plugins = [
        new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
            },
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            comments: false
        }),
    ]
}

module.exports = WebpackConfig
```

In production, I've marked `react` and `react-dom` as 'externals' because I don't want them to be bundled up in my library, it's safe to assume whatever project will be using this project will also have `reactjs`.

How do I deal with the other 3rd parties libraries which may or may not be present in whatever project is using this library? Should I exclude all 3rd party libraries from the bundle and if so how to ensure whatever project is using my library can find them?

Comment: which version of `webpack` are you using

Comment: webpack version 3.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file and you have already installed required dependencies

One of the ways to deal with third party libraries is to create a separate file, I prefer adding all the 3rd party libraries to the array and giving it to the entry point like this (You can modify it accordingly ):

```
const VENDOR_LIBS = [ 'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router' ] 
  entry: {
    bundle: 'index.js',
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  }
```

And to make sure whatever is in vendor , must not be included in bundle.js (Prevent Duplication) , you can make use of [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) inside plugins :

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor'
    }); ]
```

As this settting will be emitting two file so you can make use of [[chunkhash]](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#output-filenames) inside output object(You can modify it accordingly) :

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
```

You can read more on [Webpack Documentation Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)

If you want to know more about npm dependencies , You can see [npm-documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json)

Comment: How would a project that uses this library know which dependencies it needs to install if it doesn't include the vendor files? Would npm take care of that?

Comment: `this library` which one ?

Comment: Sorry, so using this approach, webpack creates two output files..`library.js` and `vendor.js`. Another project wants to use `library.js`, how does the project know which dependencies it needs to install to use `library.js`, if it doesn't include `vendor.js`?

Comment: well firstly you need to install dependency i.e: `npm install --save-dev dependency-name` and that will be added to your `package.json` and will be part of your project , so if `library.js` require some other dependencies (dependencies vary project to project ) you need to make sure , to install it first , if you have downloaded the project from some where it will already have `package.json`  , all the dependencies listed in `package.json` will be installed via `npm install`

Comment: Okay, so my project installs all the dependencies listed in the package.json of `library.js` if it does not have them installed already I guess, so there are no duplicates. When would you need the `vendor.js` file, for projects which don't use npm?

Comment: All the dependcies are listed in `package.json` and npm is node package manager and `vendor.js` is a part of a `webpack.config.js` , You will need `vendor.js` for a third party ( because I believe its  a good idea to separate the third party libraries (as there code does not change that frequently ) whereas `index.js` will be updated as we go along )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161455/discussion-between-aaqib-and-csharp).